# How can I implement a fast copying function like memcpy()?

Tags: c, performance, memcpy, strict-aliasing

I've seen a few answers on how `memcpy()` can achieve faster speed than a naive byte-by-byte copy. Most of them suggest something along the lines of:

```
void *my_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n) {
    uint64_t *d = dest;
    const uint64_t *s = src;
    n /= sizeof(uint64_t);

    while (n--)
        *d++ = *s++;

    return dest;
}
```

which to my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong) can violate the [strict aliasing assumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and cause undefined behavior. To keep it simple assume that `n` and the alignment and size of `src` and `dest` are multiples of 8.

If `my_memcpy` can indeed cause undefined behavior, I want to know how `memcpy` manages to copy multiple bytes at a time without violating any compiler assumptions. An example of any working implementation for x64 would help.

Suggestions to use the library routine won't work. I'm actually not writing my own `memcpy`. I'm writing a function that can use a similar optimization but AFAIK is unavailable in the C standard.

Comment: *"An example of any working implementation for x64 would help."* [sure.](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/memcpy.c)

Comment: Algorithm is very simple : copy byte/byte until alignement requirement and then use any usable trick to copy faster on correct alignement.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding here: `memcpy`, being part of the standard library and not "your code", is not bound by the same rules. So, it can use techniques that you cannot. You cannot use the inability to implement such techniques yourself as proof that the actual `memcpy` isn't using them.

Comment: for x64 it's actually this https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/sysdeps/x86_64/memcpy.S#L56 the others are fallbacks for the general case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Portably, you should copy on alignment basis, which isn't necessarily `uint64_t`. In theory, you should be using `uint_fast8_t` but in practice that one is apparently 1 byte big, 1 byte aligned on most systems. If portability isn't required, you can stick with `uint64_t`.

---

The next problem is that the pointers passed to `memcpy` are not necessarily pointing at an aligned address, as per the requirement of the standard function to work regardless of alignment. So you'll have to do something like this:

```
size_t prealign = (uintptr_t)src % _Alignof(uint64_t);
if(prealign != 0)
{
  // copy bytes up to next aligned address
}
```

Same for destination, and same for the end of the data.

---

> which to my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong) can violate the strict aliasing assumption and cause undefined behavior.

Correct. So in order to copy `uint64_t` chunks you either have to write the code in inline assembler, or you have to disable strict aliasing in a non-standard way when compiling, such as `gcc -fno-strict-aliasing`.

The "real" library memcpy is treated as a special case by the compiler, as are many other such library functions. `memcpy(&foo, &bar, sizeof(int));` will for example get translated to a single `mov` instruction, inlined in the caller code, without `memcpy` being called at all.

---

Another note about pointer aliasing is that you should `restrict` qualify the pointers as done with the real memcpy. This tells the compiler that it can assume that the `dest` and `src` pointers aren't the same, or that they overlap, meaning that the compiler doesn't need to add checks or overhead code for that scenario.

Amusingly, when I write the following naive copy function:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

void foocpy (void* dst, const void* src, size_t n)
{
  uint8_t* u8_dst = dst;
  const uint8_t* u8_src = src;

  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    u8_dst[i] = u8_src[i];
  }
}
```

Then the compiler gives me a tonne of fairly inefficient machine code. But if I simply add `restrict` to both pointers, the whole functions gets replaced with this:

```
foocpy:
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L1
        jmp     memcpy
.L1:
        ret
```

This again shows that the built-in `memcpy` is a treated as a special snowflake by the compiler.

Comment: So I guess there's no ANSI compliant enhancement after all

Comment: @AwaisChishti: There's no *strictly conforming* enhancement.  There seems to be a religion centered around the myth that use of anything not mandated by the standard makes programs non-conforming, but such a notion is contrary to what the Standard actually says.

Answer (score 4):

`memcpy` is a special function that the compiler can replace with a builtin version, e.g. if it can prove that two arrays don't overlap.

The actual, fast implementations almost always use assembler and special intrinsics (e.g. glibc with [SSSE3](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S)), but other libc implementations might implement it in C (e.g. [musl](https://github.com/esmil/musl/blob/master/src/string/memcpy.c)).

Comment: Who would have thought memcpy could be 3000+ lines of code. The SSE implementation is indeed insightful.

Comment: You can either have everything readable and short (musl) or recognize that this function is the bottleneck for a lot of programs so every optimization counts (glibc). So it's 3000+ lines for a single function for some processors, but it will be called all the time.

Comment: @tstenner: On many platforms, a readable but short `memcpy` would be a major bottleneck for code which needs to copy large objects, but slightly outperform a fancier version if used to copy many small objects.  Many implementations make more effort to avoid situations that could realistically cause an order-of-magnitude degradation in a program's *overall* performance, than those which would be unlikely to degrade performance by more than 25%.  Even a fancy `memcpy` takes twice as long as a simple one to copy a small object, most code that uses small `memcpy` operations would spend...

Comment: ...as much time computing the arguments as on the actual `memcpy` operation, so the performance impact of `memcpy` itself would be limited.

Answer (score 0):

[Tstenner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56787942/918959) already detailed the most important points.

But I'll add this: if you're coding in C and your compiler is cleverer than you, it will notice that you wrote a bad version of `memcpy` and will replace it by a call to the actual builtin `memcpy`. For example this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *mymemcpy(void *restrict dest, const void * restrict src, size_t n) {
   char *csrc = (char *)src; 
   char *cdest = (char *)dest; 

   for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++) 
       cdest[i] = csrc[i]; 

   return dest;
}
```

Compile with [GCC 9.1](https://godbolt.org/z/qcQyq9) and the resulting assembly is

```
mymemcpy:
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L7
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    memcpy
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.L7:
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
```

That, given that you're not trying to be too clever...

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that gcc will sometimes replace code that shifts as few as five bytes by one byte with a call to `memmove`.  Pretty clever.  Too bad clever and stupid aren't antonyms.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiently exploiting the features of a particular target architecture will often require the use of non-portable code, but the authors of the Standard have expressly recognized that:

> **C code can be non-portable**. [emphasis original]  Although it strove to give programmers the opportunity to write truly portable programs, the C89 Committee did not want to force programmers into writing portably, to preclude the use of C as a “high-level assembler”: the ability to write machine-specific code is one of the strengths of C. It is this principle which largely motivates drawing the distinction between strictly conforming program and conforming program (§4).

Chunking optimizations require the use of a popular extension nearly all implementations can be configured to support.  Using the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag to enable this extension in gcc and clang may yield poor performance unless code uses the `restrict` qualifier when appropriate, but that should be blamed on the failure to properly use `restrict`.  The performance penalty of `-fno-strict-aliasing` is small in code that properly uses `restrict`, while failure to use `restrict` will often impose a significant performance penalty even without `-fno-strict-aliasing`.